# create ball fall animation on given path android

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

[I want to create animation like  this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lHxr.jpg)
I create point to point animation and beizier path animation but I am not able to develop animation like this image.
Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

You can put 2 translate on the same object like this :

```
AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(true);
set.addAnimation(translateX);
set.addAnimation(translateY);
image.startAnimation(set);
```

In your case it's like gravity. So i would suggest to use accelerate interpolator on the translateY animation and a linear Interpolator on translateX.

Here is the code :

```
TranslateAnimation animationX = new TranslateAnimation(fromX,toX,0,0);
animationX.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());


TranslateAnimation animationY = new TranslateAnimation(0,0,fromY,toY);
animationX.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());

AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(true);
set.addAnimation(animationX);
set.addAnimation(animationY);
image.startAnimation(set);
```

Set the duration by using:

```
translationX.setDuration(duration);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you fore answer. currently my code is                 'imageView.animate()
                            .translationY(yy)
                            .translationX(xx)
                            .rotation(320f)
                            .scaleX(0.64f)
                            .scaleY(0.64f)
                            .setStartDelay(5500)
                            .setDuration(2250);'
So how to set your suggestion in my code?

Comment: Breakdown your animations using Translation class.
Use 2 different translations and put them in the set.

Comment: TA animationX = new TA(0.43f * width,xx,0,0); animationX.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
                    animationX.setDuration(3000);
      TA animationY = new TranslateAnimation(0,0,0.31f * height,yy);
                    animationY.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
                    animationY.setDuration(3000);
                    AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(true);
                    set.addAnimation(animationX);
                    set.addAnimation(animationY);
                    imageView.startAnimation(set);
but animation is not playing.

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct for other people.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146668/discussion-between-maulik-patel-and-sarthak-gandhi).